# Simple Read/Write to file method to access numerical data?

Tags: ios, iphone, sdk, plist

I am creating a game that actively needs to read and write to a file (presumably I assume it will be a `.plist`).

It will have approximately 5 values, with a numerical value. For example:

Stat 1: 3
Stat 2: 4
Stat 3: 1 
Stat 4: 6
Stat 5: 9

I've figured I would use a `.plist` stored in Documents for this, but I was wondering what would be the way to go, and is there an easy code snippet to easily read and write to it throughout the app?

Answer (score 2):

Checkout [NSKeyedArchiver](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html). This is a light-weight class for writing/archiving an object to a plist. There is also the corresponding [NSKeyedUnarchiver](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedUnarchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class for reading/unarchiving.

Another light-weight option you have is [NSUserDefaults.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Here's also a [tutorial](http://keeptheseinmind.blogspot.com/2011/10/nskeyedarchiver-tutorial.html) that talks a bit about both and shows how to use `NSKeyedArchiver`.

A heavier(yet more extensible and robust for larger projects or more complex model objects) is [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html). Unfortunately, this has a lot steeper learning curve too, though.

Comment: This is probably what i will end up using. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Yeah:

```
// read
NSMutableDictionary *data = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:pathToPlist];
// get
NSLog(@"Value: %@", data[@"foo"]);
// modify
data[@"foo"] = @(1337);
// write back
[data writeToFile:pathToPlist atomically:YES];
```

The plist must be located in a writable directory (i. e. adding it to the app bundle won't work).